# Compile error on assignment to array — VBA (Excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, compilation, assign, vba

I want to assign values to an Integer array, but instead I got a compile-time error.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub A()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Width(3) As Integer
    Dim TempArray As Variant
    TempArray = Array(12, 6, 12, 5)
    For i = 0 To 3
        Width (i) = CInt(TempArray(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

The error is on this line:

```
Width (i) = CInt(TempArray(i))
```

The error message is: "Compile Error. Expected:#".

I don't know what's wrong with this statement. Did I use a reserved word? I am new to VB, but I do need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Width" is an Excel reserved word. Try using something else, like "ThingWidth"

Comment: I tried and I worked, thanks! But isn't Height a reserved word? but there's no error using Height. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment led me to a little more research. `Width` isn't just an Excel reserved word, as in `Column.Width`. It's actually a VBA statement having to do with writing to text files, and it expects the number of a file opened for output.

Here's the text from Excel 2010 VBA help:

> Width # Statement
>
> Assigns an output line width to a file opened using the Open
>   statement.
>
> Syntax
>
> Width #filenumber, width
>
> The Width # statement syntax has these parts:
>
> Part Description  filenumber Required. Any valid file number.  width
>   Required. Numeric expression in the range 0–255, inclusive, that
>   indicates how many characters appear on a line before a new line is
>   started. If width equals 0, there is no limit to the length of a line.
>   The default value for width is 0.
>
> Example This example uses the Width # statement to set the output line
>   width for a file.

```
Dim I
Open "TESTFILE" For Output As #1    ' Open file for output.
VBA.Width 1, 5    ' Set output line width to 5.
For I = 0 To 9    ' Loop 10 times.
    Print #1, Chr(48 + I);    ' Prints five characters per line.
Next I
Close #1    ' Close file.
```

Comment: Really thanks a lot! You answer really makes me understand the VB Language more deeply. I learnt C long time ago and started using EXCEL VBA recently without learning VB systematically. Would it be more helpful if I spend some time to learn VB?

Comment: It's not necessary to learn VB. VBA is a great place to start. A good book will help, maybe one of John Walkenbach's. Have fun!